# Learning resource for Configuring Hibernate JPA 2.0 on Glassfish server

Tags: hibernate, glassfish, java-ee-6, jpa-2.0, glassfish-3

I am trying to create a new Java EE project using hibernate and JPA 2.0 on the glass fish server. Can you guys provide me some resources to configure the above so that they work seamlessly? I have tried using netbeans and generated the persistence unit by using the hibernate provider, but I end up getting this error:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: DBAppPU] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
```

Comment: Thanks pascal,you have become my guru

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, install Hibernate support via the [update tool](http://blogs.oracle.com/GlassFishPersistence/entry/using_hibernate_as_jpa_provider) (or follow the [manual procedure](http://blogs.oracle.com/GlassFishPersistence/entry/use_hibernate_as_a_persistence)). Second, provide a JPA 2.0 `persistence.xml` to use Hibernate as JPA provider:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd" version="2.0">
  <persistence-unit name="MyPu" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <!-- JNDI name of the database resource to use -->
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/__default</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
      <!-- The database dialect to use -->
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect" />
      <!-- update database tables at deployment -->
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
      <!-- log the generated SQL -->
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

#### Resources

- [Using Hibernate as JPA Provider for GlassFish V3](http://blogs.oracle.com/GlassFishPersistence/entry/using_hibernate_as_jpa_provider) (via update tool)
- [Use Hibernate as a persistence provider with Glassfish](http://blogs.oracle.com/GlassFishPersistence/entry/use_hibernate_as_a_persistence) (manual procedure)
- [JPA with Hibernate on Glassfish 3](http://sberka.blogspot.com/2010/04/jpa-with-hibernate-on-glassfish-3.html)

Comment: Thanks pascal, you are a true guru.I just realized that the hibernate libraries should be put on the servers folder.

Comment: Now i dont get any error but nothing turns up in the display .On checking the logs i see the following

Not binding factory to JNDI, no JNDI name configured

Comment: @BinCode Did you configure a particular datasource? What is its JNDI name? Could you test it successfully in the admin console? Also please show your `persistence.xml`.

Comment: i have added my files below please check and let me know what am i doing wrong thanks.

Comment: @BinCode I'll take a look at your problem but please open a new question. My answer covered your initial question. The current problem (even if related) is a new one and it's a best practice to not mix problems in a question (on top of that, my answer now looks odd now). So please open a new question and revert the body of this one to the one of the first revisions.

Answer (score 0):

This guidance is for integrating hibernate.4.3.5 and EJB and GlassFish.4.0 in NetBeans.8.0 IDE.
Create a web project in net beans and add hibernate jar files to the project,other setting related to configuring MySql and  glassfish is very simple so I do not describe in this article then create persistence.xml file as follow :

```
<persistence-unit name="omidashouriPU" transaction-type="Resource_Local">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/YourSchemaName"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="yourpassword"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

In Your EJB class (class that annotated with @Stateless) for creating EntityManager use following syntax :

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("omidashouriPU");
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
em = emf.createEntityManager();
em.getTransaction().begin();
em.persist(YourEntityObject);
em.getTransaction().end();

As you Know when you are using “transaction-type="Resource_Local", you have to manage the transaction by yourself, mean that, managing of opening and closing the transaction is our responsibility.
```