# Why doesn't Hibernate writes changes when using UserTransaction in Servlet?

Tags: hibernate, servlets, transactions, ejb, jta

With Hibernate:

```
@PersistenceUnit(unitName = "oracle")
private EntityManagerFactory emf;
@Resource
private UserTransaction u;

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
         EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
try {
         u.begin();
         em.persist(some entity);
         u.commit();
     } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

This doesn't write anything to the database, if I switch to EclipseLink it works ok.

If I use

```
EntityTransaction et = em.getTransaction();
```

instead of `UserTransaction` hibernates writes to the DB. (So somehow hibernate doesn't see the JTA, like EclipseLink does).

What's wrong with Hibernate ? (4.0.0-Final)
Thanks

edit:

I added the last 2 properties: (i'm using glassfish)

```
<properties>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect"/>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
    <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory" />
    <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.SunONETransactionManagerLookup" />
</properties>
```

but still doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I removed the last two properties, as they aren't necessary.
My problem was that I was creating the EM outside the `u.begin()`, and I should create it inside the transaction or call `em.joinTransaction()`.

Thanks:

I got my answer from here:
[Hibernate JPA with JTA and Glassfish Application Server doesn't seem to commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6895868/hibernate-jpa-with-jta-and-glassfish-application-server-doesnt-seem-to-commit)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that Hibernate will be aware of the JTA transaction manager to enlist itself as a transaction resource.

Configure the *hibernate.transaction.factory_class* property to *org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory* and the *hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class* property to the transaction manager lookup class for your server, e.g. *org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup*, or implement your own by inheriting from *org.hibernate.transaction.JNDITransactionManagerLookup*.

Sample *hibernate.properties*:

```
hibernate.transaction.factory_class = org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory
hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class = org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup
```

See the [Hibernate Reference Documentation, Section 3.3. JDBC connections](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch03.html#configuration-sessionfactory) for more information.

Comment: why do I have to put all this ? because I'm in Servlet ?

Answer (score 0):

For me it started working correctly only after I removed the following line:

```
<property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory" />
```